# Operator called default onErrorDropped after upgrading the Spring boot version from 2.1.7 to 2.6.4

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, reactive-programming, reactive

This code is running fine in **Springboot 2.1.7** version but after upgrading it to **Springboot 2.6.4** it throws exception. Unable to rectify the issue. Let me know where I have to change in code

```
 fun getScheduledTasks(): Flux<*> {
        return Flux.fromIterable(tasks)
                .filter {
                    logger.info("{} was enabled? {}", it::class.qualifiedName, it.config.enabled)
                    it.config.enabled
                }
                .flatMap { task ->
                    Flux.interval(task.config.initialDelay, task.config.interval)
                            .flatMap {
                                logger.info("Beginning task ")
                                task.execute()
                                    .doOnNext {
                                        logger.info("Completed task {}", task::class.qualifiedName)
                                    }
                                    .onErrorResume { err ->
                                        logger.warn(“Error in running {}.", task::class.qualifiedName, err)
                                        Mono.empty()
                                    }
                            }
                            .doFinally {
                                logger.warn(“Taskcompleted unexpectedly: {}", it.name)
                            }
                }
    }
```

**Exception:**

```
2022-07-18 12:05:49.649  INFO 5440 --- [     parallel-1] c.u.cpp.background.runner.Runner         : Beginning  task 
2022-07-18 12:05:49.657 ERROR 5440 --- [ntLoopGroup-3-5] reactor.core.publisher.Operators         : Operator called default onErrorDropped

reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.lang.NullPointerException: t is null in sink.next(t)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: t is null in sink.next(t)
    at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:228)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$SerializedFluxSink.next(FluxCreate.java:147)
    at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.BatchCursorFlux$$Lambda$1536/0x0000000067460320.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.BatchCursorFlux.lambda$recurseCursor$4(BatchCursorFlux.java:94)
    at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.BatchCursorFlux$$Lambda$1535/0x0000000067d52a20.accept(Unknown Source)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:171)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:854)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.success(MonoCreate.java:165)
    at
```